# How do I use a hash to modify the values of an Array?

Tags: ruby

I am building a base converter. Here is my code so far:

```
def num_to_s(num, base)
remainders = [num]

while base <= num   
 num /= base  #divide initial value of num
 remainders << num       #shovel results into array to map over for remainders
end

return remainders.map{|i| result = i % base}.reverse.to_s   #map for remainders and shovel to new array

puts num_to_s(40002, 16)

end
```

Now it's time to account for bases over 10 where letters replace numbers. The instructions (of the exercise) suggest using a hash. Here is my hash:

```
conversion = {10 => 'A', 11 => 'B', 12 => 'C', 13 => 'D', 14 => 'E', 15 => 'F',}
```

The problem is now, how do I incorporate it so that it modifies the array? I have tried:

```
return remainders.map{|i| result = i % base}.map{|i| [i, i]}.flatten.merge(conversion).reverse.to_s
```

In an attempt to convert the 'remainders' array into a hash and merge them so the values in 'conversion' override the ones in 'remainders', but I get an 'odd list for Hash' error. After some research it seems to be due to the version of Ruby (1.8.7) I am running, and was unable to update. I also tried converting the array into a hash outside of the return:

```
Hashes = Hash[remainders.each {|i, i| [i, i]}].merge(conversion)
```

and I get an 'dynamic constant assignment' error. I have tried a bunch of different ways to do this... Can a hash even be used to modify an array? I was also thinking maybe I could accomplish this by using a conditional statement within an enumerator (each? map?) but haven't been able to make that work. CAN one put a conditional inside an enumerator?

Comment: I've gotta ask: why are you using an eight-year-old version of Ruby?

Comment: it came with my imac, which is about 6 years old and still OS 10.6.8 - I tried to update my ruby today and it failed, somewhere in the stream of errors, i got the impression it was telling me I need to update my operating system, which is an ordeal unto itself and I am trying to avoid. I hear horrible things about Yosemite. But if i MUST, I will.

Comment: You really should upgrade, at least to Mavericks, then install [RVM](https://rvm.io) ("Ruby Version Manager) and use it to install and switch among Ruby versions. RVM is a little confusing at first, but just follow the step-by-step instructions and you'll be OK. I suggest you use the latest version of Ruby (currently 2.2).

Comment: I will def look into it, but for now I am thinking maybe I should use Nitrous? It may be the best quick alternative until I hash out upgrading my system.

Comment: Of [possible interest](http://cbednarski.com/articles/installing-ruby/). I've read about Nitrous but haven't used it.

Comment: it's awesome. it provides you with a terminal&text editor that runs the most current version of Ruby. Great for folks with a PC that don't want to go through the drama of setting up Ruby on their computer, or for people like myself that have old versions and haven't figured out (lol) how to update. You can save files in nitrous as well. If you use it like that, it's kind of like Cloud for your Ruby...access it anywhere ;) Check it out! Thanks for the link btw...I have a lot on my plate and Nitrous is the quick solution...but I will reference that link when I have a chance to update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use a hash:

```
def digit_hash(base)
  digit = {}      
  (0...[10,base].min).each { |i| digit.update({ i=>i.to_s }) }
  if base > 10
    s = ('A'.ord-1).chr
    (10...base).each { |i| digit.update({ i=>s=s.next }) }
  end
  digit
end

digit_hash(40) 
  #=> { 0=>"0",   1=>"1",   2=>"2",   3=>"3",  4=>"4",
  #     5=>"5",   6=>"6",   7=>"7",   8=>"8",  9=>"9",
  #    10=>"A",  11=>"B",  12=>"C",      ..., 34=>"Y", 35=>"Z",
  #    36=>"AA", 37=>"AB", 38=>"AC", 39=>"AD" }
```

There is a problem in displaying digits after 'Z'. Suppose, for example, the base were 65. Then one would not know if "ABC" was 10-11-12, 37-12 or 10-64. That's detail we needn't worry about.

For variety, I've done the base conversion from high to low, as one might do with paper and pencil for base 10:

```
def num_to_s(num, base)
  digit = digit_hash(base)
  str = ''
  fac = base**((0..Float::INFINITY).find { |i| base**i > num } - 1)
  until fac.zero?
    d = num/fac
    str << digit[d] 
    num -= d*fac
    fac /= base                   
  end
  str
end
```

Let's try it:

```
num_to_s(134562,10) #=> "134562" 
num_to_s(134562, 2) #=> "100000110110100010" 
num_to_s(134562, 8) #=> "406642" 
num_to_s(134562,16) #=> "20DA2" 
num_to_s(134562,36) #=> "2VTU"
```

Let's check the last one:

```
digit_inv = digit_hash(36).invert
digit_inv["2"] #=>  2 
digit_inv["V"] #=> 31 
digit_inv["T"] #=> 29 
digit_inv["U"] #=> 30
```

So

```
36*36*36*digit_inv["2"] + 36*36*digit_inv["V"] +
  36*digit_inv["T"] + digit_inv["U"] 
  #=> 36*36*36*2 + 36*36*31 + 36*29 + 30
  #=> 134562
```

The expression:

```
(0..Float::INFINITY).find { |i| base**i > num }
```

computes the smallest integer `i` such that `base**i > num`. Suppose, for example,

```
base =    10
num  = 12345
```

then `i` is found to equal `5` (`10**5 = 100_000`). We then raise `base` to this number less one to get the initial factor:

```
fac = base**(5-1) #=> 10000
```

Then the first (base-10) digit is

```
d = num/fac   #=> 1
```

the remainder is

```
num -= d*fac #=> 12345 - 1*10000 => 2345
```

and the factor for the next digit is:

```
fac /= base  #=> 10000/10 => 1000
```

I made a couple of changes from my initial answer to make it 1.87-friedly (I removed `Enumerator#with_object` and `Integer#times`), but I haven't tested with 1.8.7, as I don't have that version installed. Let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: @ Cary I have to admit, I am really new to Ruby and a lot of your solution is over my head at this point. I haven't learned a lot of the methods you used yet (but google is my friend) That's the tricky thing for a newb on a forum full of pro's...lol..I tried to run it and I am getting errors - perhaps that too is a 1.8.7 issue. Even though I don't totally understand it now, I am going to pick it apart until I do ;) Thank you!! I learn a lot from you guys!

Comment: Going step-by-step, and making calculations in IRB, you should be able to figure it out, but let me know if you have problems. [String#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-next) returns the next character, in a smart way: `'C'.next #=>'D'; 'Z'.next #=>'AA'; '9'.next #=>'10'`. Say `h = {'a'=>1, 'b'=>2}`. [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) works like this: `h.update({'c'=>3}) #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}`, [Hash#invert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) like this: `h.invert  #=> {1=>"a", 2=>"b"}`.

Comment: ahhhh that new version is, off the top, at least a little easier for me to tell what is happening ... I am still however getting the error   //undefined method `digit_hash' for main:Object//   am I supposed to include  //digit_inv = digit_hash(36).invert // somewhere to make it run correctly? *** thanks for breaking down those methods, that was easy to understand =D

Comment: Perhaps first go through with `num=1234` and `base = 10`, doing the calculations with paper and pencil. Then go through again with `base = 16`.

Comment: There should be an error message right after you ran `def def digit_hash(base)...end`. What is the error message and on which line did it occur? (Or did you forget to run that code before running `def num_to_s...end`? :-) )

Comment: You caught me. I wasn't running the first block. How embarrassing, lol. I need some sleep. But I am running everything now :) I am getting the error : test.rb:14:in `num_to_s': uninitialized constant Float::INFINITY (NameError)
 from test.rb:25

Comment: That's another version problem. Change `Float::INFINITY` to `1/0.0`. If that doesn't work, replace it with a largish number like `1000`.

Comment: POW!!!!!!! that worked!!! :) :) the 1/1.0 did it! thank you! you have been really patient!

Comment: I'm off to bed. Let me know if you have any other problems. If you are able to understand everything that's going on, I'd like to know that as well.

Comment: will do! i'm off to bed as well and will be looking this over again tomorrow ;)

Comment: haven't forgot about this, just had to move on for a while (i spent too much time on this one problem already) and I will come back to it with a fresh eyes later ;)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from question, you can use Fixnum#to_s(base) to convert base.

```
255.to_s(16) # 'ff'
```

Comment: unfortunatly the directions state not to use that built in method

Comment: @seinna You don't have to reinvent the wheel. Fixnum already have base converting functionality. You can use it if your purpose is not for practicing.

Comment: but i didn't know .to_s could be used as a base converter, that's interesting! ;)

Comment: but in this case it IS for practicing, it is part of an assignment so to speak (I'm just learning Ruby) and I can't use the built-in method, I have to recreate what it does... but like i said i didn't know .to_s could act as a converter and that's pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a

```
def get_symbol_in_base(blah)
  if blah < 10
    return blah
  else
    return (blah - 10 + 65).chr
  end
end
```

and after that do something like:

```
remainders << get_symbol_in_base(num)
return remainders.reverse.to_s
```

Comment: I can see where your going with this... but i'm not quite there with you yet... i get an 'undefined method `char' for 63933': Fixnum   on the line //                                                                                                                                                           return (num - 10 + 65).char //                                                                   ....also, i do know that this is converting the num to it's ascii equivalent,  but what is the logic behind the -10 + 65 bit?

Comment: ..also @Mircea, just so I know in the future and don't waste countless hours trying a million ways to accomplish it...CAN a hash be used to modify and array? And can a conditional be used in an enumerator such as #map or #each? I have searched for examples everywhere but came up empty on both fronts (maybe that should be my hint? lol).... but I'm not sure if it can't be done or I just can't find an example of it

Comment: huh... did you put in chr or char? the idea is pretty simple: 65 is 'A', so anything that is >=10 will land on A,B,C,D, etc. For example: 11 would be: 11-10+65 => 66. chr for 66 is B.

Comment: I don't see a reason why a hash could not be used in operations that modify an array

Comment: the problem that you have in your code is that you are mixing hash and array operations.

Comment: did not try it out, but it would be something along the lines of: return remainders.map{|i| result = i % base}.map{|x| x<10 ? x.to_s : conversion[x]}.reverse.to_s

Comment: good call. I definitely wrote .char instead of .chr! I will take a closer look at my code to see how I am mixing operations. Thanks for the example of using a conditional in a enumerator, it's very helpful. Is it safe to say that it would be limited to a single ternary - no elsif's allowed?